# How to change h2 span text boxes into rectangle shape?

Tags: css

As the title says i am trying to make two h2 and span text boxes have a rectangular shape for a website and i need help.

mine's looks like this:

[image]

but i want them to look like this:

[image]

```css
h2 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20rem;
  left: 11rem;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

h2 span {
  background-color: #556272;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: normal;
  padding: 2rem;
}

h2 span:first-child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 44px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

h2 span:last-child {
  transform: translate(-1rem, -1rem);
  width: 200px;
  height: 44px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<h2>
  <span>Web</span> <br />
  <span>Development</span>
</h2>
```

Comment: We don't need the whole webpage code, can you just reduce the code to the **relevant part**?

Comment: So, i remove from the html or from the ccs?

Comment: Both, remove anything NOT related to the problem.

Comment: Note that the [<br>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer if it solved your problem or helped in finding the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just my take, but it seems like it'd be easier and more readable to do something like this:

```css
h2 div { 
  /* various styles for background and colors */
  background-color: #ccc;  /* just an example */
}

h2 div.first-line {
  display: block;
  max-width: 200px; /* or whatever */
  margin-left: 200px;

}

h2 div.second-line {
  display: block;
  max-width: 200px; /* or whatever */
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<h2>
  <div class='first-line'>Web</div>
  <div class='second-line'>Development</div>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Removing Defauilt styling

Headers by default have more margin on the top. You just want to normalize your styling.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

This should do the trick, as it removes all margins from all elements. Just put it at the top of your stylesheet. But there are also some [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) defaults out there that remove all unwanted default styling.

You can also change the styling on the element itself, or remove all styling from it:

```
h2 {
  all: unset;
}
```

But usually removing all default styling like this is not what you want. I'm just saying it's **an option**.

I usually just start styling by starting from something like this:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  background-color: #eee;
  /* Some other defaults, like maybe flex attributes depending on your layout. */
}
```

*Tip: When using the browser development tools, you can inspect each tag and see all the styling it has. Try changing / removing things in there, until you've found the culprit of your issues.*